# How can i get the DomainName\AccountName with the .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, vb.net, dns, account

How can i get the

> DomainName\AccountName

as string with the .NET Framework?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

Comment: +1, but actually you wouldn't need to call `ToString()` as `Name` is already of type string.

Comment: @0xA3: Good point - think I got a bit carried away with myself there :-)

Comment: Note that calling this in asp.net mvc controller returns the AppPool rather than the currently connected user if you're using Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [`Environment.UserDomainName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userdomainname.aspx) property to retrieve the domain and [`Environment.UserName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username.aspx) to retrieve the user name:

```
Dim domainAndUserName As String _
    = Environment.UserDomainName & "\\" & Environment.UserName
```

Comment: Incorrect. Environment.UserDomainName only contains the domain, not the username.

Comment: @CERIQ: Sorry, I misread the docs and corrected my answer. Strange that it still received upvotes...

Answer (score 2):

`Environment.UserDomainName` contains the domain/computer name that your account is joined to. `Environment.UserName` contains only the username. To get the result you're after, you need to concaternate the variables(`Environment.UserDomainName & "\\" & Environment.UserName`). This only works well in a local context though, if you use this code in a website, you'll get the account name that your application pool is running under. In asp.net, use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` instead.

Comment: Before joining domain name and user name first check if the domain name is not empty in case of local users.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using ASP.NET you can use

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

`WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`